# Fuel economy and trip planning at warp

Tags: star-trek, warp, transwarp

Is there any way to calculate how much anti-matter or dilithium I'll need to travel 5 light years at warp 4 (a general equation would be great, but if not the a ballpark estimate)?

If different engines from different generations have different fuel efficiency, I'd be open to whichever is most convenient to calculate, though it would also be nice to know how this has changed over the generations.

Comment: In which series? There's a big difference between Star Trek and TNG

Comment: This is not a duplicate - it is asking how much fuel is needed for the trip (as well as speed).

Comment: @Richard If I have to choose I'd say Star Trek: Enterprise, but I'll take what you can give me. Would also be interesting to know how fuel economy has improved over the years.

Comment: @Hack-R - That makes the question very much wider and less answerable.

Comment: @Richard I'll take whatever you can give me... let's say TNG? If you have an answer for one series but not the other the question can be made specific to that series.

Comment: @Hack-R - I've voted to close since the question hasn't been edited to reflect your comments

Comment: @Richard I don't understand. I said if someone has an answer for a specific generation (TNG) then I could make the question specific to that, but I was given no indication that there's an answer for any given series. Also, can't you directly edit the question?